# Weird POSIX behaviour for two closely time strings with and without specifying the format

Tags: r, posix, posixct

I don't fully understand the behavior of converting data and time strings to `POSIX` objects. For example, I have a vector of two strings representing date and time. Conversion w/o specifying the format ignore the time portion, and set the timezone to IST:

```
as.POSIXct(c('2017-03-24 02:59:59', '2017-03-24 03:00:00'))
[1] "2017-03-24 IST" "2017-03-24 IST"
```

But when I specify the format, it sets to a different timezone, and fails for the string where the hours are '2', but not if the time is a second latter.

```
as.POSIXct(c('2017-03-24 02:59:59', '2017-03-24 03:00:00'), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
[1] NA "2017-03-24 03:00:00 IDT"
```

Three questions:

1. Why the time zone differs between the two lines
2. Why when no format is given it ignores the times' portion.
3. Why does it fail to convert the first string when the format is specified?

Comment: The date/time conversion is smart enough to recognize that daylight saving time started. There are plenty of other question on this site dealing with this very issue.

Comment: And there was no such hour 2:59:59 on that date? But it depends of course on the timezone. What if I don't know what time zone was it recorded, and I don't care about. All I need is consistency.

Comment: To ensure consistency specify the timezone with the `tz` option in the `as.POSIXct(x, tz = " ", format...)`.  Using standard time "IST" should work.

Comment: My console does things differently than yours, apparently. Without specifying `tz=`, I do not get `NA`. When I include `tz="IST"`, I get warnings, as `"IST"` is not in the list (`OlsonNames()`, long vec of known zones), though I can reproduce it with `tz="Israel"` (which is in `OlsonNames()`). Time zones are hugely problematic when spanning daylight savings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Why the time zone differs between the two lines

As said in the comments, it differs due to daylight savings. Since you don't include the zone in the call to `as.POSIXct`, you are prone to many problems. When at all possible, be explicit with timezone. This is a no-kidding moment: if you know it (and it is not part of the string), *never* assume it will be inferred correctly. In my experience, it will get it wrong enough to be really annoying and very difficult to detect, find, and fix.

---

> 2. Why when no format is given it ignores the times' portion

It does not, though it might look like it. This is only a symptom of how it is *printed*, not stored. (This is common in many of R's functions, for instance how it shows `pi` with only a handful of decimal places while it is certainly storing many more. Without this "representation versus actual precision" model, R's console would be unnecessarily full of decimal places and such, all the time.)

If I update your code to explicitly include zone:

```
as.POSIXct(c('2017-03-24 02:59:59', '2017-03-24 03:00:00'), tz="Israel")
# [1] "2017-03-24 IST" "2017-03-24 IST"
as.POSIXct(c('2017-03-24 02:59:59', '2017-03-24 03:00:00'), tz="Israel") + 1
# [1] "2017-03-24 00:00:01 IST" "2017-03-24 00:00:01 IST"
```

In the second case, I added one second to the times, and you see the time is now there. You can look at the internals to see it in a different way:

```
dput(as.POSIXct(c('2017-03-24 02:59:59', '2017-03-24 03:00:00'), tz="Israel"))
# structure(c(1490306400, 1490306400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
# ), tzone = "Israel")
dput(as.POSIXct(c('2017-03-24 02:59:59', '2017-03-24 03:00:00'), tz="Israel")+1)
# structure(c(1490306401, 1490306401), tzone = "Israel", class = c("POSIXct", 
# "POSIXt"))
```

Times are stored as floating point numbers and a special class. Between the two (without and with a 1-second addition), you can see that the numbers are just off-by-one.

A third way to confirm is to take the "missing time" posix objects and explicitly print to something (which is no longer `POSIXct`, but it's just for demo):

```
a <- as.POSIXct(c('2017-03-24 02:59:59', '2017-03-24 03:00:00'), tz="Israel")
a
# [1] "2017-03-24 IST" "2017-03-24 IST"
format(a, format="the time is %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# [1] "the time is 2017-03-24 00:00:00" "the time is 2017-03-24 00:00:00"
```

---

> 3. Why does it fail to convert the first string when the format is specified?

As @Dave2e commented, according to the daylight savings conversions, that time "never happened".

According to https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/israel/jerusalem?year=2017:

> Mar 24, 2017 - Daylight Saving Time Started
>
> When local standard time was about to reach
>   Friday, March 24, 2017, 2:00:00 am clocks were turned forward 1 hour to
>   Friday, March 24, 2017, 3:00:00 am local daylight time instead.

I interpret that to mean that the clock shifted from `01:59:59` to `03:00:00`, so `02:**:**` never happened. R is telling you with the `NA` that that time should not have occurred. There are certainly ways (hacks) you can *infer* that this is the case: find all `NA` values, then attempt to re-convert using plus or minus an hour; if the new value is not `NA`, then you found another instance where R thinks that time is not possible. If it is still `NA`, then there must be something else about the string (additional characters, different order, etc).

In my experience, I have not found this logic to ever be incorrect (though I don't know with certainty that it is flawless), even if it seems annoying. When I thought it might have been incorrect, I have always found something else that explained why I think I have *that precise time*:

- data collection stored the wrong TZ
- data collection failed to store the TZ, and I inferred incorrectly
- some conversion in the pipeline mis-converted the times and/or zone(s)
- likely something else I haven't rooted out

Comment: Thanks for the details answer. I'm almost ready to accept that. But in your first example: ` as.POSIXct(c('2017-03-24 02:59:59', '2017-03-24 03:00:00'), tz="Israel") + 1`, it demonstrates the opposite from what you claims. As the output of the two times is `"2017-03-24 00:00:01 IST"`. I would expect the first one to output `"2017-03-24 03:00:00 IST"`. But from what you described it did lose the time from the input.

Comment: Perhaps we're talking about two things. I interpreted "lose time" as "only `%y-%m-%d` was shown". If you are saying that it shifted from 3am to midnight, then the problem is not my code but in the understanding of timezone assignment. In your first example, what timezone do you think `'2017-03-24 03:00:00'` is supposed to be in?

Comment: I do understand why 3am is printed as midnight. but why a second before midnight plus a second gives midnight plus a second instead of midnight sharp? `as.POSIXct('2017-03-24 02:59:59', tz="Israel") + 1` outputs `"2017-03-24 00:00:01 IST"` while `as.POSIXct('2017-03-24 02:59:59', tz="US/pacific") + 1` outputs `"2017-03-24 03:00:00 PDT"` (Notice the second difference).

Comment: I see your point ... that IS interesting, I glossed over that and never noticed it. And of course, it is particular to that timezone (well, among all 592 timezones in `OlsonNames()`, only `"Asia/Jerusalem" "Asia/Tel_Aviv"  "Israel"` show this phenomenon ...). Okay, so for *that* I have no answer/excuse.